# How to start the dashboard micro integrator wso2 ei 7.0

Tags: wso2, wso2-enterprise-integrator, integrator, wso2-micro-integrator, wso2-esb

I try to start service micro integrator wso2 7.1.0
[Enterprise Integration 7.1.0 Micro integrator](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NfnHd.png)

but, i cant open dashboard https://localhost:9743/dashboard/login

[This site can’t be reached](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xBZe5.png)

what i missed ?

Answer (score 0):

It is because, when you start Micro Integrator, the monitoring dashboard does not start automatically. It is separate from the Micro Integrator runtime. You need to start the dashboard in a different terminal and connect it to the runtime. https://ei.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/micro-integrator/administer-and-observe/working-with-monitoring-dashboard/#setting-up-the-dashboard